# Double trigger after pushing a button in React-native

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, react-native, aws-sdk

I would like to apply two functions, do 2 actions after pushing a simple button on React-Native.
To be honest, it should be very simple but somehow, the second one is never executed.

```
//Clean static function in its own class
class Aws {
  static register(phonenumber, username, password) {
    ClientConf = {
      "UserPoolId" : "eee",
      "ClientId" : "eee",
      "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
    console.log("Aws Register");
    AWSCognito.config.region ="ccc"; 
    var poolData = { 
      UserPoolId : "bbb", // Your user pool id here
      ClientId: "aaa"
    };
    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var attributeList = [];
    var dataPhoneNumber = {
      Name : 'phone_number',
      Value : phonenumber
    }
    var attributePhoneNumber = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);
    attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);
    userPool.signUp(username, password, attributeList, null, function(err, result){});
  }
}

//Register Page, react-native Component

class RegisterPage extends Component {
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    return (<View>
      <Text style={styles.saved}>Create an account</Text>

      <Form
        ref='registrationForm'
        onFocus={this.handleFormFocus.bind(this)}
        onChange={this.handleFormChange.bind(this)}
        label="Personal Information">

        <InputField
          ref='username' 
          placeholder='Username' 
          placeholderTextColor="#888888" />

 <InputField
          ref='phoneNumber' 
          placeholder='Phone Number' 
          placeholderTextColor="#888888"  />

        <InputField
          ref='password' 
          placeholder='Password' 
          placeholderTextColor="#888888" />
        </Form>

<TouchableHighlight> 
      onPress={Aws.register(this.state.formData.phoneNumber, this.state.formData.username, this.state.formData.password) && this.gotoNext.bind(this)}
      underlayColor='#78ac05'>
      <View><Text>Register</Text></View></TouchableHighlight>

  </View>);
  }

  gotoNext() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'MainPage',
      name: 'mynamedpage',
    });
  }
}
```

I tried to simplify the code to the best I could.

The problem is occuring at this line:

```
  onPress={Aws.register(this.state.formData.phoneNumber, this.state.formData.username, this.state.formData.password) && this.gotoNext.bind(this)}
```

The first function is well-executed but my screen does not move to the next page.
When moving to:

```
  onPress={this.gotoNext.bind(this)}
```

The page is changing well. And in this case:

```
  onPress={this.gotoNext.bind(this) && Aws.register(this.state.formData.phoneNumber, this.state.formData.username, this.state.formData.password)}
```

Only the second function is executed.

How can I manage to execute those two actions? I do not see any logics in the previous tests.
Also, I tried putting them both in a single function but the problem remains. 
Note that the code has been simplify at its best on purpose (removed constructor etc...) and is compiling well.

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating away in callback function of `userPool.signUp()` You can pass callback as parameter to your `Aws.register()` function

```
//Clean static function in its own class
class Aws {
  static register(phonenumber, username, password, callback) {
    ClientConf = {
      "UserPoolId" : "eee",
      "ClientId" : "eee",
      "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
    console.log("Aws Register");
    AWSCognito.config.region ="ccc"; 
    var poolData = { 
      UserPoolId : "bbb", // Your user pool id here
      ClientId: "aaa"
    };
    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var attributeList = [];
    var dataPhoneNumber = {
      Name : 'phone_number',
      Value : phonenumber
    }
    var attributePhoneNumber = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);
    attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);
    userPool.signUp(username, password, attributeList, null, function(err, result){ callback() });
  }
}

//Register Page, react-native Component

class RegisterPage extends Component {
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    return (<View>
      <Text style={styles.saved}>Create an account</Text>

      <Form
        ref='registrationForm'
        onFocus={this.handleFormFocus.bind(this)}
        onChange={this.handleFormChange.bind(this)}
        label="Personal Information">

        <InputField
          ref='username' 
          placeholder='Username' 
          placeholderTextColor="#888888" />

 <InputField
          ref='phoneNumber' 
          placeholder='Phone Number' 
          placeholderTextColor="#888888"  />

        <InputField
          ref='password' 
          placeholder='Password' 
          placeholderTextColor="#888888" />
        </Form>

<TouchableHighlight> 
      onPress={Aws.register(this.state.formData.phoneNumber, this.state.formData.username, this.state.formData.password, this.gotoNext.bind(this))}
      underlayColor='#78ac05'>
      <View><Text>Register</Text></View></TouchableHighlight>

  </View>);
  }

  gotoNext() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'MainPage',
      name: 'mynamedpage',
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In your example, callback() is undefined. Plus, I am not sure if I can pass the view/component into th callback function in a different class to execute gotoNext() in the right context.

Comment: Did you modify both places, also onPress()? I added extra parameter

Comment: Thanks it looks like there is some kind of infinite loop on the register() function after this change, I don't really understand. Going to debug it into the details